# Counting threads using thread_local

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

I wrote a following class:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

class ThreadCounter
{
    static inline std::atomic<std::size_t> thread_count = 0;
    static thread_local ThreadCounter instance;

    ThreadCounter()
    {
        ++thread_count;
    }
    ~ThreadCounter()
    {
        --thread_count;
    }

public:
    static size_t get()
    {
        return thread_count;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ThreadCounter::get() << std::endl;
}
```

I expect it to print `1`, but I see `0`.

I assumed that for each thread started, the `instance` would be constructed (I was quite certain because I observed such behavior some time ago in another case) and increment the counter. However, the value returned is always zero.

I also tried putting the instance outside of the class, both with `static t_l` and `t_l`-only specifiers, both in the header and in a separate `.cpp` file. None of these worked.

Is there some trick to make it work, or is this approach impossible?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Example of what, calling the `get()` function? LMAO OK.

Comment: LMAO ? what is that?

Comment: @herhor67 There are as many ways to call your method as there are developers. If you provide a MRE, it reduces the cognitive load of  people helping you. That's a good thing. You shouldn't be rude about it like you are.

Comment: To make people happy, it's nice to post a single snippet of code that can be compiled as is (yours is close, remove `Example:` and add `#include <iostream>`). Your question can be easily answered without a [mre], but asking for one becomes somewhat of a kneejerk reaction, and providing one is customary.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I think I described clearly what kind of behaviour was expected. Thread started -> `thread_local instance` is constructed. Nothing was said about creating additional instances manually. But if you have a suggestion what the MRE should look like in this case, please share.
Edit: Alright, already answered by @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: You realize there are no threads in your at all are you?

Comment: @PepijnKramer What about the main thread?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat touche ;) Off by one error by me

Comment: If the counter of threads is `thread_local`, as in it's local to one thread, what is it for? Counting threads spawned by each thread? It can't count all of the threads because other threads will have their own instance and thus their own counter.

Comment: @user4581301 `instance` is global `thread_local`, which *should* get constructed on thread start, and add to the "global" `static` counter, which is common for all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread_local` variables are weird.

Global `thread_local` variables are not constructed when you start a thread. Rather, they are constructed when you first access them from a given thread.

You don't access `instance` anywhere, so it's not constructed.

Comment: Alright, and I assume that in-class `static`s are treated just like globals, therefore there is no way for it to work?

Comment: @herhor67 I don't know how to make it work. There might be OS-specific APIs to count threads.

Comment: Well there probably are, but I meant about its current form.
I know I can read number of threads on linux from some specific `/self/` file.